# What's the difference between TMU and openGL's GL_TEXTUREn?

Tags: mobile, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0, texture-mapping

I can't quite understand what's the difference.
I know TMU is a texture mapping unit on GPU, and in opengl, we can have many texture units.I used to think they're the same, that if I got n TMU, then I can have n GL_TEXTURE to use, but I found that this may not be true.
Recently, I was working on an android game, targetting a platform using the Mali 400MP GPU.According to the document, it has only one TMU, I thought that I can use only one texture at a time.But suprisingly, I can use at least 4 textures without trouble.Why is this?
Is the hardware or driver level doing something like swap different textures in/out automatically for me? If so, is it supposed to cause a lot of cache miss?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not the ultimate hardware architecture expert, particularly not for Mali. But I'll give it a shot anyway, based on my understanding.

The TMU is a hardware unit for texture sampling. It does not get assigned to a OpenGL texture unit on a permanent basis. Any time a shader executes a texture sampling operation, I expect this specific operation to be assigned to one of the TMUs. The TMU then does the requested sampling, delivers the result back to the shader, and is available for the next sampling operation.

So there is no relationship between the number of TMUs and the number of supported OpenGL texture units. The number of OpenGL texture units that can be supported is determined by the state tracking part of the hardware.

The number of TMUs has an effect on performance. The more TMUs are available, the more texture sampling operations can be executed within a given time. So if you use a lot of texture sampling in your shaders, your code will profit from having more TMUs. It doesn't matter if you sample many times from the same texture, or from many different textures.

Answer (score 2):

Texture Mapping Units (TMUs) are functional units on the hardware, once upon a time they were directly related to the number of pixel pipelines. As hardware is much more abstract/general purpose now, it is not a good measure of how many textures can be applied in a single pass anymore. It may give an indication of overall multi-texture performance, but by itself does not impose any limits.

OpenGL's `GL_TEXTURE0+n` actually represents Texture Image Units (TIUs), which are locations where you bind a texture. The number of textures you can apply simultaneously (in a single execution of a shader) varies per-shader stage. In Desktop GL, which has 5 stages as of GL 4.4, implementations must support 16 unique textures per-stage. This is why the number of Texture Image Units is 80 (16x5). GL 3.3 only has 3 stages, and its minimum TIU count is thus only 48. This gives you enough binding locations to provide a set of 16 unique textures for every stage in your GLSL program.

---

GL ES, particularly 2.0, is a completely different story. It mandates support for at least **8** simultaneous textures in the fragment shader stage and **0** (optional) in the vertex shader.

```c
const mediump int gl_MaxVertexTextureImageUnits   = 0; // Vertex Shader Limit
const mediump int gl_MaxTextureImageUnits         = 8; // Fragment Shader Limit

const mediump int gl_MaxCombinedTextureImageUnits = 8; // Total Limit for Entire Program
```

There is also a limit on the number of textures you can apply across all of the shaders in a single execution of your program (`gl_MaxCombinedTextureImageUnits`), and this limit is *usually* just the sum total of the limits for each individual stage.